# jQuery dataTables - Remove an HTML element from a cell

Tags: jquery, datatables

Trying to dynamically edit cells based on different JQuery events. This is what I'm hoping that should be done to the data (putting together the fns in simpler way)

```
var d = table.cell(rowindex,cellindex).node().remove(".custom-class1");
table.cell(rowindex,cellindex).data(d);
```

Example data on cell,

```
<td>
  <span class="custom-class1"></span>
  <span class="custom-class2"></span>
</td>
```

The cell data should be replaced with,

```
<td>
  <span class="custom-class2"></span>
</td>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you bit be specific on what kind if jQuery events you want to do this??

Comment: In jquery you can try replaceWith  http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: and what have you tried ? what problem are you having ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup

```
var d = table.cell(rowindex,cellindex).node().remove(".custom-class1");
```

would never work. `node()` returns a DOM node, not a jQuery object (use [**`to$()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/to%24()) or `toJQuery()` for that), and `remove(".custom-class1")` would remove the *entire* `<td>` anyway.

To remove a particular `<span>` you should use `$('span-selector').remove()`. `$somethingContainingSpans.remove('.class')` removes `$somethingContainingSpans` as well.

I would retrieve the content as jQuery instance, work on it and put it back. The following removes `<span class="custom-class1">class1</span>` when you click on a cell :

```
table.on('click', 'td', function() {
   var $data = table.cells(this).nodes().to$();    
   //or just -> var $data = $(table.cell(this).data());  
   $data.find('span').remove(".custom-class1");
   table.cell(this).data($data.html());
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ka4v78jd/**

NB: Using `cells(this).nodes()` (the plural methods) since `to$()` not seems to work with `cell()` nor `node()` - but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to remove a span via row and column specification, or just class. If its just class, try:

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
    var className = $('#classHolder').val();
    $('.'+className).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <span class="custom-class1">custom-class1</span>
  <span class="custom-class2">custom-class2</span>
</td>
<br><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Example: custom-class1" id="classHolder" /><button id="button">Remove Class</button>
```